# SQLException for Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity, sqlexception

I have a very simple question.

I made a Stored Procedure for my SQL and it looks like this:

```
    IF(@CurrentStatus='Fulfilled')
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Opps, this item is too hot to last too long. It is SOLD OUT!',16, 1)
        RETURN -1           
    END
```

It will return a error message when the condition is meet.

In my C# code behind, I am using a try-catch block.

I simply want to display the error message from the above Stored Procedure to the screen. So which exception type I should use?

Here is my code:

```
            try
        {
            storeDB.AddToBuyingOrders(newOrder);
            storeDB.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Result"] = "Added";
            return View();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            TempData["Result"] = ex.InnerException.Message.ToString();
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why do you ask question for that? You could catch `Exception` put a breakpoint in your code and got the answer within few seconds!!! It even took me less then five minutes to make working example just because I was curious about what problem is there that you don't do it yourselves.

Correct exception type to catch is `EntityCommandExecutionException` or its parent `EntityException`. The `SqlException` will be in its `InnerException` property and you will get your message there.

Comment: I should use UpdateException, not EntityCommandExecutionException ... But still thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: What? If SaveChanges is in try block the exception will be handled in catch block. If it is not it means that it wasn't fired. Where do you actually use that procedure?